# Is it guaranteed to get name in placemark after geocoding is successful?

Tags: ios5, geocoding, clgeocoder

So if I typed address of a business, (so it's forward geocoding)
will I surely get the name of business in placemark?

when I tried some addresses such as apple headquarter, I got the name in placemark.
However, it seems like I don't always get the name.

Or, will I be able to find the location of business with name?

Sorry if the answer of this question is well known. I wasn't sure how to type this in google.

Comment: The CLGeocoder will try its best using what data is available to it, but first you should be absolutely sure the address is right. Typing addresses into mobile devices can be tricky and -- in my experience -- often results in errors. Are you verifying the validity of the address first? If so, correct addresses should yield accurate place-name lookups. (Try Googling "address verification API")